# How can I access the list of timesheet approvers in the AtTask API?

Tags: api, rest, attask

With the latest release of AtTask the UI has beed extended so that it is now possible to define a list of people as approvers for a timesheet (former it was only possible to define exactly one user as the approver).

How can I get the list of approvers for a timesheet through the API ?
Currently it seems only to be possible to get on approver per timesheet (Timesheet - Field "ApproverID").

Is there any possibility to get the additional approvers.

Answer (score 0):

This is only able to be obtained using the unsupported API as this is a new feature.
but the following call should pull a list of all approvers

```
attask/api-unsupported/tshet/{timesheetID}?fields=approversListString
```

Note- the unsupported link is just that unsupported so all functions used under this may not work as expected or be fully developed.